# WebSphere : How to retrieve a user's credentials from CAS ticket?

Tags: java, websphere, cas

I am currently working on a WebSphere 8.5.5 secured by LDAP.
What I want to achieve is SSO using Jasig CAS authentication.
Currently, I am able to log a user in CAS and to retrieve and validate the ticket in a WebSphere hosted webapp.
What I wonder how to do is to retrieve the login and password of the identified subject using the ticket I am recieving (if this is possible...)

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to be connecting to a CAS Server that has the ClearPass module enabled. Then you can securely retrieve the user's password to replay it.

[1] https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/integration/ClearPass.html

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for your answer, this looks like what I was looking for!! :)